# mod_proxy_ajp (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, timeout, mod-proxy-ajp

I am using mod_proxy_ajp with Tomcat and I receive the following error:

> (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ajp_ilink_receive() can't
>   receive header

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the connection timeout.

My original configuration was:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

After adding the 'timeout' parameter:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ timeout=600
```

You could follow these links to get more information and other examples:

- [Setting timeout for all the ProxyPass mappings in Apache Server mod_proxy directive [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829025/setting-timeout-for-all-the-proxypass-mappings-in-apache-server-mod-proxy-direct)
- [Apache TimeOut directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout)